# Overeager struct packing warnings with `__attribute__((packed))`?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, arm

I'm implementing a binary logging system on a 32 bit ARM mcu (Atmel SAM4SD32C, a Cortex-M4/ARMv7E-M part), and in the process of designing my data structures. My goal is to describe the log format as a packed struct, and simply union the struct with a char array, for writing to the log device (a SD card, via FatFS, in this case).

Basically, I have a very simple struct:

```
typedef struct adc_samples_t
{
    int32_t adc_samples[6];

    uint64_t acq_time;

    int8_t  overrun;
    uint8_t padding_1;
    uint8_t padding_2;
    uint8_t padding_3;

} __attribute__((packed, aligned(4))) adc_sample_set;
```

Now, my architecture is 32 bits, so as far as I understand, access to any member /other/ then the `overrun` member should be 32-bit aligned, and therefore not have an extra overhead. Furthermore, the `aligned(4)` attribute should force any instantiations of the struct to be on a 32-bit aligned boundary.

However, compiling the above struct definition produces a pile of warnings:

```
        In file included from ../src/main.c:13:0:
<snip>\src\fs\fs-logger.h(10,10): warning: packed attribute causes inefficient alignment for 'adc_samples' [-Wattributes]
          int32_t adc_samples[6];
                  ^
<snip>\src\fs\fs-logger.h(12,11): warning: packed attribute causes inefficient alignment for 'acq_time' [-Wattributes]
          uint64_t acq_time;
```

As far as I know (and I'm now realizing this is a big assumption), I assumed that 32-bit alignment was all that was needed for optimal component positioning on 32 bit arm. <strike>Oddly, the only member that does /not/ produce warnings are the `overrun` and `padding_X` members, which I don't understand the causes for.</strike> (Ok, the [ARM docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABFAIGG.html) say `Byte accesses are always aligned.`)

What, exactly, is going on here? I assume (possibly incorrectly) that the struct instantiation will be on 4 bytes boundaries. Does the compiler require a more broad alignment (on 8 byte boundaries)?

---

Edit: Ok, digging into the ARM docs (the magic words here were "Cortex-M4 alignment":

> 3.3.5. Address alignment
>
> An aligned access is an operation where a word-aligned address is used for a word, dual word, or multiple word access, or where a halfword-aligned address is used for a halfword access. Byte accesses are always aligned.
>
> The Cortex-M4 processor supports unaligned access only for the following instructions:
>
> LDR, LDRT
>   LDRH, LDRHT
>   LDRSH, LDRSHT
>   STR, STRT
>   STRH, STRHT
>
> All other load and store instructions generate a UsageFault exception if they perform an unaligned access, and therefore their accesses must be address aligned. For more information about UsageFaults see Fault handling.
>
> Unaligned accesses are usually slower than aligned accesses. In addition, some memory regions might not support unaligned accesses. Therefore, ARM recommends that programmers ensure that accesses are aligned. To trap 
>   accidental generation of unaligned accesses, use the UNALIGN_TRP bit in the Configuration and Control Register, see Configuration and Control Register.

How is my 32-bit aligned value not word-aligned? The user guide defines "Aligned" as the following:

> Aligned
>   A data item stored at an address that is divisible by the
>   number of bytes that defines the data size is said to be aligned.
>   Aligned words and halfwords have addresses that are divisible by four
>   and two respectively. The terms word-aligned and halfword-aligned
>   therefore stipulate addresses that are divisible by four and two
>   respectively.

Comment: What keeps you from cleanly serialising the `struct`?

Comment: @Olaf - Padding bytes. I need packed structs so I can canonically know the data structure. This data file is going to be read by a different platform (probably python) on a different architecture (x86). Dealing with data-files where the format is dependent on the vagaries of compiler struct padding is /NOT/ fun.

Comment: What about "**cleanly** serialising" was not clear? Type-punning is certainly **not** clean.

Comment: How else /do/ you serialize a struct, then? I can't afford manually shifting everything out or more copying. FWIW, I have approximately 100 clock cycles per byte. Also, while I have access to a `malloc()`, my heap is very limited, so it'd be very much preferred if everything was statically allocated.

Comment: "I can't afford manually shifting everything out" - did you profile? With a good modern compiler like gcc, it is less costly than you might think - presuming you use a standard pattern! I still have to see code your statement is true for such like logging. After all, you have to read that log somehow lateron; if that is not the same as the writer, your reader depends on the same format/endianess and packing (which is not guaranteed). Oh, and if you really need 100 clocks/byte, your code is really poorly written; as a raw estimation, it takes at most 10 clocks done properly.

Comment: As a sidenote: If you use a heap, you very likely do something else wrong. In embedded systems, using a heap is far my most times a bad idea. Use either static memory or pools.

Comment: @laf Profile with what? Did you read the question? This is on a [sam4s](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATSAM4SD32B.aspx). There are no profilers available.. I'm running FreeRTOS (ergo, the heap, I wouldn't use one otherwise), but under some memory pressure. 100 clocks/byte is my ceiling for keeping up with the data rate, not my actual use, and there is a bunch of other housekeeping/interrupts stuff going on.

Comment: @olaf Really, the question isn't "how do you think I should implement this thing (given the fact that there are a pile of requirements that aren't enumerated in the question)". I just want to know what the heck GCC means when it says my struct member accesses are unaligned, because I'm pretty sure they are aligned.

Comment: You might've misunderstood what `packed` means: setting the alignment of all structure members to the minimum possible value, 1.

Comment: Yes, I have understand that. I'm then placing the struct members so that things that are 4 bytes wide are after 4 1-byte members, etc, so the alignment works. Basically, I'm doing http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: For the example struct, assuming the struct instantiation starts on a aligned boundary (`aligned(4)`), the first `uint32_t` member will be at offset 0, followed by 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, the `uint64_t` member is at offset 24 (which is 8-byte aligned), and then there are 4 single-byte members the alignment of which is not critical. Am I missing something here?

Comment: On most sane platforms, the compiler aligns structures to the largest alignment requirement of any member. This is logical because the first member must be aligned, and a host of other reasons. Is that not the case with Cortex-M4?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I have no freaking idea. I would assume so, but for some reason, my struct that starts with a `uint32_t` produces a warning that said `uint32_t` is not aligned. Even if I use the GCC directive that explicitly forces 4-byte alignment, I *stll* get the warning. At this point, I'm looking at the disassembly, and I'm relatively confident it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @FakeName: Since I learned reading, I try to use it. The Cortex-M4 has a cycle counter built-in in most - if not all - implementations. You say there is no DWT? Did you check? I did not say to use a full-size profiler. Nevertheless, a simple look at the assembly code would suffice here. Most arithmetic operations, including arbitratry bitshifts take 1 clock cycle. plus the or, which takes another cycle, plus a store and 1 load at worst (1/4 for `uint32_t`). Some clocks for a loop can be spent (or unroll it, so there is no overhead).

Comment: That means your CPU might require value to be naturally aligned. It might work without that, but then, it reads the fields byte-wise and assembles them for **every** access. Which is exactly what serialisation does, but (once more:) **for every access**.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: It is left to the integrator of the CPU core. And it is only supported for the basic accesses, not e.g. load/store multiple, double, etc. Which can cause trouble with optimisations. Smaller MCUs often spare the extra gates for the alignment unit. Which is inefficient anyway, as it only supports 1/2/4 byte accesses, thus has to use 3 (instead of the minimum 2 accesses) for an odd-address aligned word access.

Comment: @Olaf - I'm genuinely not sure what you point is, at this point. I can make sure the buffers I'm using for this stuff is statically allocated, and by structuring things nicely, I actually managed to avoid a incidental copy in one place. The data is written into my output structure in larger chunks (32-bit writes for most of the members), and then read out in a single pass, without needing any shifting or anything.

Comment: So..... yes, I think the current approach I'm taking is optimimal, given the constraints I have (which are completely irrelevant to the question, by the way). The question was, in it's entirety "why does GCC emit this warning for what I'm confident is a correctly aligned struct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, at this point, I'm somewhat confident that the warning is being emitted in error.

I have a statically defined instance of the struct, and at one point I zero it:

```
adc_sample_set running_average;
int accumulated_samples;

inline void zero_average_buf(void)
{

    accumulated_samples = 0;

    running_average.adc_samples[0] = 0;
    running_average.adc_samples[1] = 0;
    running_average.adc_samples[2] = 0;
    running_average.adc_samples[3] = 0;
    running_average.adc_samples[4] = 0;
    running_average.adc_samples[5] = 0;

    running_average.overrun = 0;

    running_average.acq_time = 0;

}
```

The disassembly for the function is the follows:

```
{
004005F8   push {r3, lr}         
    accumulated_samples = 0;
004005FA   movs r2, #0       
004005FC   ldr  r3, [pc, #36]        
004005FE   str  r2, [r3]         
    running_average.adc_samples[0] = 0;
00400600   ldr  r3, [pc, #36]        
00400602   str  r2, [r3]         
    running_average.adc_samples[1] = 0;
00400604   str  r2, [r3, #4]         
    running_average.adc_samples[2] = 0;
00400606   str  r2, [r3, #8]         
    running_average.adc_samples[3] = 0;
00400608   str  r2, [r3, #12]        
    running_average.adc_samples[4] = 0;
0040060A   str  r2, [r3, #16]        
    running_average.adc_samples[5] = 0;
0040060C   str  r2, [r3, #20]        
    running_average.overrun = 0;
0040060E   strb.w   r2, [r3, #32]        
    running_average.acq_time = 0;
00400612   movs r0, #0       
00400614   movs r1, #0       
00400616   strd r0, r1, [r3, #24]
```

Note that `r3` in the above is `0x2001ef70`, which is indeed 4-byte aligned. `r2` is the literal value `0`.

The `str` opcode *requires* 4-byte alignment. The `strd` opcode only requires 4 byte alignment as well, since it appears to really be two sequential 4-byte operations, though I don't know how it actually works internally.

---

If I intentionally mis-align my struct, to force the slow-path copy operation:

```
typedef struct adc_samples_t
{
    int8_t  overrun;
    int32_t adc_samples[6];

    uint64_t acq_time;


    uint8_t padding_1;
    uint8_t padding_2;
    uint8_t padding_3;

} __attribute__((packed, aligned(8))) adc_sample_set;
```

I get the following assembly:

```
{
00400658   push {r3, lr}         
    accumulated_samples = 0;
0040065A   movs r3, #0       
0040065C   ldr  r2, [pc, #84]        
0040065E   str  r3, [r2]         
    running_average.adc_samples[0] = 0;
00400660   ldr  r2, [pc, #84]        
00400662   strb r3, [r2, #1]         
00400664   strb r3, [r2, #2]         
00400666   strb r3, [r2, #3]         
00400668   strb r3, [r2, #4]         
    running_average.adc_samples[1] = 0;
0040066A   strb r3, [r2, #5]         
0040066C   strb r3, [r2, #6]         
0040066E   strb r3, [r2, #7]         
00400670   strb r3, [r2, #8]         
    running_average.adc_samples[2] = 0;
00400672   strb r3, [r2, #9]         
00400674   strb r3, [r2, #10]        
00400676   strb r3, [r2, #11]        
00400678   strb r3, [r2, #12]        
    running_average.adc_samples[3] = 0;
0040067A   strb r3, [r2, #13]        
0040067C   strb r3, [r2, #14]        
0040067E   strb r3, [r2, #15]        
00400680   strb r3, [r2, #16]        
    running_average.adc_samples[4] = 0;
00400682   strb r3, [r2, #17]        
00400684   strb r3, [r2, #18]        
00400686   strb r3, [r2, #19]        
00400688   strb r3, [r2, #20]        
    running_average.adc_samples[5] = 0;
0040068A   strb r3, [r2, #21]        
0040068C   strb r3, [r2, #22]        
0040068E   strb r3, [r2, #23]        
00400690   strb r3, [r2, #24]        
    running_average.overrun = 0;
00400692   mov  r1, r2       
00400694   strb r3, [r1], #25        
    running_average.acq_time = 0;
00400698   strb r3, [r2, #25]        
0040069A   strb r3, [r1, #1]         
0040069C   strb r3, [r1, #2]         
0040069E   strb r3, [r1, #3]         
004006A0   strb r3, [r1, #4]         
004006A2   strb r3, [r1, #5]         
004006A4   strb r3, [r1, #6]         
004006A6   strb r3, [r1, #7]
```

So, pretty clearly, I'm getting the proper aligned-copy behaviour with my original struct definition, **despite** the compiler apparently incorrectly warning that it will result in inefficient accesses.

Comment: ANd you think **that** latter is faster than the clean way? Btw: the compiler **has** to generate the worst-case code if it does not know the placement in advance (which it does for a statically aligned `struct` in the same function, but not if you e.g. pass it by pointer.

Comment: Everything I'm doing (here) is statically defined, so I can guarantee the first code version will be used. You keep mentioning the "clean" way, that I have yet to see.

Comment: If there is a better, "cleaner" way to serialize a struct then unioning it with a byte array, I'm all ears, but I haven't seen it. Manual, explicit serializing by shifting out each member would be horrible and messy and involve a lot of repeated boiler-plate code, and I can't see any way that could be regarded as an improvement.

Comment: This question is quite old, but I had a similar problem with GCC 10.3.  Despite the warning indicating `[-Wattributes]`, I found that it was controlled by the `-Wpacked` option: "Warn if a structure is given the packed attribute, but the packed attribute has no effect on the layout or size of the structure. Such structures may be mis-aligned for little benefit."  It seems that it warns of _potential_ inefficiency if the packed struct is used in specific ways.

Answer (score 4):

> I assumed that 32-bit alignment was all that was needed for optimal component positioning on 32-bit ARM

It is.

But you don't *have* 32-bit alignment here *[in the originally-asked question]* [because](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes):

> Specifying the `packed` attribute for `struct` and `union` types is equivalent to specifying the `packed` attribute on each of the structure or union members.

[given that](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes):

> The `packed` attribute specifies that a variable or structure field should have the smallest possible alignment—one byte for a variable, and one bit for a field, unless you specify a larger value with the `aligned` attribute.

In other words, if you still want a packed structure to still have some minimum alignment after you've forced the alignment of all members, and thus the type itself, to nothing, you need to specify so - the fact that that might not actually make `-Wpacked` shut up is a different matter - GCC may well just spit that out reflexively before it actually considers any further alignment modifiers.

Note that in terms of serialisation, you don't necessarily need to pack it anyway. The members fit in 9 words exactly, so the only compiler padding anywhere is an extra word at the end to round the total size up to 40 bytes, since `acq_time` forces the struct to a natural alignment of 8. Unless you want to operate on a whole array of these things at once, you can get away with simply ignoring that and still treating the members as one 36-byte chunk.

Comment: How can a struct containing only 32 bit values *not* have the values aligned on 32 bit boundaries?

Comment: Wait. Does the the packed flag affect the instantiation of the variable somehow? I've told the compiler to not add padding bytes (which is *all* the `__attribute__((packed))` does, afict). If the struct is instantiated on a non-aligned address, it would be an issue, but the warning is being thrown on the struct definition, not an instantiation.

Comment: Ok, even specifying `struct adc_samples_t { int32_t adc_samples[6]; } __attribute__((packed, aligned(4)));` doesn't make the warning go away. With that attribute, I *do* have 32 bit alignment.